# Two collections displayed in the URL via iron:router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have two collections:

```
var Books = new Meteor.Collection("books");
var Chapters = new Meteor.Collection("chapters");
```

The `Chapter` collection has a propetry called `bookId`. So each chapter has a book and each book has many chapters.

This is the router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route("bookList", {
    path: "/",
    data: function() {
      return Books.find({});
    }
  });
  this.route("bookPage", {
    path: "/books/:_id",
    data: function() {
      return Books.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
  });
});
```

So now when I open a book I get and URL like:

```
http://localhost:3000/books/TS23MTKrdpja2tCwq
```

But now I don't know how to modify the code so I can open a book's chapter and end up with an URL like:

```
http://localhost:3000/books/TS23MTKrdpja2tCwq/chapters/stwtwfd5tsrstfw
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

**chapters/chapter_page.js:**

```
Template.chapterPage.helpers({
  chapters: function() {
    Chapters.find({
      bookId: this._id
    }, {
      sort: {
        position: 1
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**chapters/chapter_item.html:**

```
{{#with chapter}}
  <h4><a class="open-chapter" href="{{pathFor 'chapterPage'}}">{{title}}</a></h4>
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a chapter route with two parameters.

The `_id` in the chapter route obviously references the chapter, and the `bookId` property name must be the same as in the chapter collection for this to work.

This will allow for something like :

```
{{#with chapter}}
  {{! 1.0.0-pre2 syntax}}
  {{pathFor route="chapterPage"}}
  {{! 0.9.3 syntax}}
  {{pathFor "chapterPage"}}
{{/with}}
```

To compute automatically the chapter URL given a chapter document.

Given that `chapter` is referencing a chapter document : our `data` function exposes a chapter property that is indeed a chapter document.

EDIT :

Your `chapters` is probably wrong because this._id probably references nothing at all (would need to use something like `this.chapter.bookId` or `this.book._id`). I would include the chapters as a property in the `data` result like this :

```
this.route("chapterPage", {
  path: "/books/:bookId/chapters/:_id",
  data: function() {
    var chapter=Chapters.findOne(this.params._id);
    var book=Books.findOne(this.params.bookId);
    var chapters=Chapters.find({
      bookId:this.params.bookId
    },{
      sort:{
        position:1
      }
    });
    return {
      chapter:chapter,
      book:book,
      chapters:chapters
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What's exactly `someChapter`? How do I make that work?

Comment: What's the difference of just doing: `{{pathFor 'chapterPage'}}`?

Comment: `someChapter` was intended to represent any template accessible helper that references a valid chapter document (with `_id` and `bookId` set to properly construct the URL). The `{{pathFor route="chapterPage"}}` is the proper syntax for the very latest version of `iron:router`. Edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks. One last question, could you see my *EDIT*? I added the *with* part in the section I show above but now all the items disappeared. I did it the wrong way?